# How do I mock the return value of a react hook passd as a prop when testing with jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, ts-jest, framer-motion

I'm trying to write a unit test for a [Card compenent](https://github.com/uwemneku/windows-store/blob/main/components/HeroCards.tsx) using Jest. This component takes a [framer-motion value](https://www.framer.com/docs/motionvalue/) and a ref as Props. This values can only be created using the useMotionValue and useRef hook.

```
interface Props {
   currentIndex: MotionValue<number>;
   containerRef: RefObject<HTMLDivElement>;
}
```

Currently, I'm able to pass in a dummy value for the ref using `document.createElement`, but when i tried creating a motion value to pass into the component, I get an error saying that react hooks cannot be used ouside a component

```
    it("renders a card", () => {
    const container = document.createElement("div");

    render(
      <Card
        containerRef={{ current: container }}
        currentIndex={******}  // motion value goes here
      />
    );

  });
```

I had to render the component in a parent component first and then test the parent Component but i was wondering, is there a way to mock the motion value and pass it in as a prop?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to mock `useMotionValue` implementation. You can use `jest.mock` at the top of your file where you write your test for the component that uses this hook. Remember also to not mock other functionality by requiring actual implementation.

```
// at the top of the file that tests component with useMotionValue call
jest.mock('framer-motion', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('framer-motion'),
  useMotionValue: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
    // put here the mock implementation of MotionValue methods
  })
}));
```